# Laravel - How to switch between databases dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project I have tow phase first one is to create databases and tables in Mysql dynamically with input field (Host, Username, Password, Database) in client side. Second one and there is my question how to switch between them dynamically with drop-down list of databases and thank you.

Comment: Obligatory: where's the code, what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

use query builder DB::connection('your_connection')->table('your_table_in_connection')